# Trying to use a procedure to fill in info about variables using a custom structure

Tags: vb.net

I'm in a highschool comsci class and I'm using vb.net.
I'm trying to use a procedure to fill in info for each structure variable that I make, issue is that the procedure won't accept individual variables using the structure and will just use the structure type.

```
Structure instInfo
        Dim vol As Double
        Dim cost As Double
        Dim amt As Integer
        Dim bpm As Double
        Dim costMult As Double
        Dim indivVol As Double
End Structure

    Dim snare As instInfo
    Dim hiHat As instInfo
    Dim tom As instInfo
    Dim bass As instInfo
    Dim clap As instInfo
    Dim cymbal As instInfo

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        defineInst(snare, 1, 10, 1, 60, 1.3, 1)
        defineInst(hiHat, 0, 100, 0, 120, 1.2, 0.2)
        defineInst(tom, 0, 5000, 0, 45, 1.4, 1.5)
        defineInst(bass, 0, 20000, 0, 15, 1.8, 4)
        defineInst(clap, 0, 100000, 0, 120, 1.3, 0.8)
        defineInst(cymbal, 0, 500000, 0, 5, 2, 10)
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
```

above is the declaration of the structure and each variable. Structure and each variable using the structure is global.
Below is the defineInst procedure I'm using

```
 Sub defineInst(inst As instInfo, vol As Double, cost As Double, amt As Integer, bpm As Double, costmult As Double, indivVol As Double)
        inst.vol = vol
        inst.cost = cost
        inst.amt = amt
        inst.bpm = bpm
        inst.costMult = costmult
        inst.indivVol = indivVol
    End Sub
```

When I run the program, none of the values for any of the instruments are changed and when I put a block it says that the "inst" variable has been assigned as "{ASSIGN_FINAL.Form1.instInfo}" when in the first run, I believe it should just say "snare".

Am I missing something, or is it just not possible to run a procedure with a structure variable?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `Structure` is passed by value, so the `inst` variable in the `defineStructure()` method is a **copy** of the value passed in. The method then makes changes to the copy, which are **thrown away** as soon as the method exits. The original is never modified.

There are three ways to solve this:

1. Change the `defineInst()` method from `Sub` to `Function`, so it will `Return` a **new instance** of your type, and assigns this to the variable. This solves the issue because the changes made in the method now make it back to the original variable.
2. Change from `Structure` to `Class`, and then also update the variable declarations to include the `New` keyword. Most professional developers assume `Class` by default anyway, and only use `Structure` when they have a good reason. This fixes the issue because only the reference is copied when passing the variable to the method, so changes made via this reference are still modifying the same original object.
3. Change the method signature so `inst As instInfo` is `ByRef inst As instInfo`. This is the quickest and easiest fix in the moment, but I'd definitely consider the resulting code to be lower-quality.

I recommend you **do both 1 and 2**. Going just a little further, I would also change `defineInst()` to be a **constructor** of your type.

Here is the class:

```
Public Class instInfo
    Public vol As Double
    Public cost As Double
    Public amt As Integer
    Public bpm As Double
    Public costMult As Double
    Public indivVol As Double

    Public Sub New(vol As Double, cost As Double, amt As Integer, bpm As Double, costmult As Double, indivVol As Double)
        Me.vol = vol
        Me.cost = cost
        Me.amt = amt
        Me.bpm = bpm
        Me.costMult = costmult
        Me.indivVol = indivVol
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then use it like this:

```
' Where are these declared? 
' It seems like they should have an access modifier like `Private` or `Public` instead of `Dim`.
Dim snare  As instInfo
Dim hiHat  As instInfo
Dim tom    As instInfo
Dim bass   As instInfo
Dim clap   As instInfo
Dim cymbal As instInfo

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    snare  = New instInfo(1R,     10R, 1,  60R, 1.3R,   1R)
    hiHat  = New instInfo(0R,    100R, 0, 120R, 1.2R, 0.2R)
    tom    = New instInfo(0R,   5000R, 0,  45R, 1.4R, 1.5R)
    bass   = New instInfo(0R,  20000R, 0,  15R, 1.8R,   4R)
    clap   = New instInfo(0R, 100000R, 0, 120R, 1.3R, 0.8R)
    cymble = New instInfo(0R, 500000R, 0,   5R,   2R,  10R)
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

Or this:

```
' Where are these declared? 
' It seems like they should have an access modifier like `Private` or `Public` instead of `Dim`.
Dim snare  As New instInfo(1R,     10R, 1,  60R, 1.3R,   1R)
Dim hiHat  As New instInfo(0R,    100R, 0, 120R, 1.2R, 0.2R)
Dim tom    As New instInfo(0R,   5000R, 0,  45R, 1.4R, 1.5R)
Dim bass   As New instInfo(0R,  20000R, 0,  15R, 1.8R,   4R)
Dim clap   As New instInfo(0R, 100000R, 0, 120R, 1.3R, 0.8R)
Dim cymbal As New instInfo(0R, 500000R, 0,   5R,   2R,  10R)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

BTW, the `R` character added to the end of those number literals tells the compiler they are actually `Double` values, instead of `Integer`, in order to match the data type expected by the method. This saves you cast/conversion work when the program runs, making it ever-so-slightly faster. Moreover, that the code compiled without them indicates neither `Option Strict` nor `Option Infer` are on. You should have one of those enabled. To do otherwise is very poor practice.